# php5 $_SESSION security

Tags: security

I read sessions and security questions on stackoverflow, and much beyond.  I think I know the answer, but I want to confirm it with one concise  simple question--security is too important.

**Conjecture**: My black hat web visitor does not have direct access to his $_SESSION contents.

that is, after my server executes

```
  $_SESSION['myuserprivilege']='user' ;
```

I can assume that even the most clever blackhat cannot somehow find out even that my code did this, interrogate to what my php program set his server $_SESSION to (both keys and contents), or (much worse) engineer `$_SESSION['myuserprivilege'] = 'admin'`.  only my own server php code can do so.

I still have to be concerned that a blackhat can steal the cookie of a different admin user ( => https and session rotation).  but that's a different issue.

correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values of the session are stored in your server, not in the user machine. So, no... No one can see or set that value without access to your server or any security problem in your code. It's like money in a safe, only who have access can get it or if the safe isn't secure enough.

And about cookie stealing, this is called session hijacking. It's common tecnique used to steal a session from another user. You can get more information [here](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Session_hijacking_attack).

Basically if a person get the id of the session of a logged admin and the application doesn't have any approach to avoid this kind of situation, this person can have access to that user privileges.

Anyone can set a cookie in your website, but sessions has one thing called "PHP Session ID", so to get some value from a session, this person need to know a valid session id that have privileges to some part of application.

Session routation is not a problem, the chances to get some session from anyone that have this privileges is really, really hard. You also can use more characters in your session to make it more harder, but o don't think it's necessary.

**Final answer:** No one cannot set a session in our website, just who has access do the code and your server can do it.

Comment: Given how I phrased my final question, I think the answer starts with *yes, you are correct* then.  can you please add it at the top so I can mark it answered?

Comment: I added a final answer at the bottom, ok?